# Text to speech pronouncing numbers like "4th", "8ths", or "2nd"

Tags: android, text-to-speech

A while back I wrote some code that would convert a Double into a String, where the string was formatted as a readable fraction.

For an example

```
4.75 => "4 and 3 4ths"
1.5 => "1 and 1 half"
1.33 => "1 and 1 3rd"
```

The majority of numbers are pronounced as intended with a few notable exceptions. Instead of the text "4ths" being pronounced as "fourths" it is pronounced "four tee ache ess". Here is an example demonstrating this.

```
//this works
tts.speak("1 and 3 fourths", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);    
//this works
tts.speak("1 and 1 3rd", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); 
//this works
tts.speak("1 and 1 4th", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); 

//this does not work
tts.speak("1 and 3 4ths", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
//this does not work
tts.speak("1 and 3 4thes", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
//this does not work
tts.speak("1 and 3 4th-s", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

The strangest this is that this worked fine about a year back when I first wrote the code, the "ths" postfix was pronounced as one might expect. Perhaps I am mistaken on that point...

Regardless, the issue seems to be that numbers followed by 2 letters are read like a complete word, while numbers followed by 3 or more are read like a series of digits instead. I *could* add to the complexity of the algorithm by substituting all the numbers for their word counterparts however the longer I work at this the more I begin to think that I am reinventing the wheel. The [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E)) did not seem to denote a way of specifying pronunciation for the speak() method. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of behavior is going to vary between TextToSpeech Engines -- the Google TTS engine, for example, will behave differently than, say, the SVOX PICO (emulator < API 24) engine... so it's not your fault how each engine behaves slightly differently... and if there are any pronunciation controls, then the engine is responsible for supplying them directly to the end user via settings.

You're probably just testing on a different engine than you were before... or even an update to the same engine.

You could just test some major engines like Samsung, Google, and PICO and try to find a common denominator of behavior.  I suspect that you're right: spelling out the words is the best option in this case.

You can specify what engine you want to use as the last argument (String) of the TextToSpeech constructor, and you can see what engines are installed on any particular device by going to (home\settings\language&locale\TTS) or in code like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> whatEnginesAreInstalled(Context context) {
    final Intent ttsIntent = new Intent();
    ttsIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(ttsIntent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    ArrayList<String> installedEngineNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ResolveInfo r : list) {
        String engineName = r.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        installedEngineNames.add(engineName);

        // just logging the version number out of interest
        String version = "null";
        try {
            version = pm.getPackageInfo(engineName,
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).versionName;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("XXX", "try catch error");
            }
        Log.i("XXX", "we found an engine: " + engineName);
        Log.i("XXX", "version: " + version);
    }
    return installedEngineNames;
}
```

Comment: Yes this makes a lot of sense. As it turns out another team had reset the handheld to factory settings fairly recently in an unrelated issue. I assume that updates were later applied and my engine (package com.google.android.tts) was updated sometime during that sequence. I just ended up biting the bullet and spelling out the words for the sake of deadlines.

Answer (score 1):

As Boober Bunz explained, these features vary from one engine to another. It might get changed with newer versions of engine as well. I would suggest the best option will be to convert everything to words, like ***Fourths*** to make it consistent across engines. For a quick fix you can try ***4th's*** as it seems to be more valid word than others you mentioned not working.

Comment: Solid thought, I got pretty exited for a bit there but unfortunately "4th's" ended up getting pronounced "fourth ess". I ended up going with the "fourths" text like I originally mentioned in my question but that apostrophe was a good idea.