# Java TextToSpeech - How do i make my text sound like a question?

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I have a simple text to speech app using `TextToSpeech`.   I can't get it to sound like it is asking a question.

```
TextToSpeech mTts;
...
String textInString = "Do you want coffee?";
mTts.speak(textInString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

My code works perfectly well.  I just can't get my "voice" to ask things.
Is it possible using this library?
If not, is there any free library which would?

Comment: Would you like some coffee?   Would you care for some coffee?

Comment: same basic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392804/text-to-speech-pronouncing-numbers-like-4th-8ths-or-2nd